# $q.all(p1, p2).then() appears to fire before both promises are resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Are $resource promises supposed to be compatible with $q? Perhaps I am using it wrong. I have two $resource objects that I might load like:

```
$rootScope.foos = Res1.query();    // [ foo1, foo2...]
$rootScope.bars = Res2.query();    // [ bar1, bar2...]
```

I need to broadcast an event when both (and only both) queries have arrived. So I'm using $q.all like this:

```
$q.all([$rootScope.foos.$promise, $rootScope.bars.$promise])
.then(function(){
    // sometimes $rootScope.bars == []
    $rootScope.$broadcast('foos_and_bars!');
});
```

Event listeners find that $rootScope.bars is empty / `[]` (when a second later it has data)

---

*Update in response to @Daiwei* and @ExpertSystem

Ok here's the JSFiddle for this:  **[Reproducing JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJ9xx/3/)**

The console shows $q.all() being returned before the promises are resolved. I suppose either it's being used wrong or it is an angular bug having to do with any of [$resource, $scope, $http, etc.]...

Comment: Can you post related code in `Res1.query()`?

Comment: This should have worked fine. Could you prepare a fiddle or **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: @ExpertSysterm ok here we go, reproduces nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/mJ9xx/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an accidental version conflict between ngResource and angular. Angular was on 1.2.6 but ngResource was on 1.2.3.

The originally posted fiddle was not working for a similar but different ngResource version problem, namely that it was using an old ngResource version which didn't use to expose the $promise objects (although they were still used under the hood). In later versions of ngResource the promises are exposed so they can be used for things like this.

@ExpertSystem's suggestion is good but would not have fixed the issue. I did try with $q.defer() promises prior and it has the same issue when the version conflict is present. It *does* work in the absence of the version conflict, but then it is unnecessary, no need to create your own promises when they are already given to you for convenience.

Here's the [**working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mJ9xx/5/)   (at `angular 1.2.1`  but that is good enough for ngResource)

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE:

It turned out to be a version-conflict issue. 
The solution provided below is working with later versions (tested with 1.2.8), but is totally redundant.
See  **[Purrell's answer](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource)** for more info.

---

Quoting the docs on **[`$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource)**:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method **immediately returns an empty reference** (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a callback function for the action methods.
>   [...]
>   The Resource **instances** and collection have these additional properties:
>
> - $promise: ...
> - $resolved: ...

Your `Res1` and `Res2` are $resource **objects** (not *instances*) and (as per the docs) invoking the `query()` method *"immediately returns an empty reference"* (in your case an array). (**UPD**: The returned arrays still have the additional properties though.)

As the docs suggest, most of the time you just assign those empty references to the Scope and forget about them (once the data is fetched the model (and subsequently the view) will get automagically updated).

---

Yet, if you do have reasons for wanting to get explicitly informed as soon as the data is there, you could use two "real" promises:

```
// Create two deferred objects
var deferred1 = $q.defer();
var deferred2 = $q.defer();

// As soon as the data arrives, resolve the deferred objects
$rootScope.foos = Res1.query(function () { deferred1.resolve(); });
$rootScope.bars = Res2.query(function () { deferred2.resolve(); });

// Combine their promises using `$q.all()`
$q.all([deferred1.promise, deferred2.promise]).then(...);
```

See, also, this **[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wXB2E/)**.

---

**UPDATE**

Since the returned arrays also have the `$promise` property, the more concise version is:

```
$rootScope.foos = Res1.query();
$rootScope.bars = Res2.query();

$q.all([$rootScope.foos.$promise, $rootScope.bars.$promise]).then(...);
```

**[Working demo](https://codepen.io/ExpertSystem/pen/EVJNQL?editors=001)**

Comment: Good input but I would note 1) The reference is not just an empty array. It has $promise and $resolved properties (for you to use). It's  mentioned on the page you linked. Search for "The Resource instances and collection have these additional properties". 2) Using the $promise objects exposed by $resource is OK, that's what they are there for. 3) those $promise props are "real" promise, and ultimately created through $q. </list> So.. it turned out to be a version conflict! more notes in my answer space low here. I really thank you for the time and thought here though, very much appreciated.

Comment: That's strange. I (thought I had) tried with the latest versions and both `$promise` and '$resolved` where undefined. That led me to misinterpret the docs. I tried again now and it works as you said. What a shadowy conspiracy :)

Answer (score 0):

After your $q.all()...you can use .spread(function(prom1, prom2){} instead to run once all promises are returned. With the way you are currently doing it the .then will fire every time one item in the array returns, hence why sometimes one of the items from your array are empty.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a .spread function in the docs for $q http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q . Are you referring to a different promise implementation?

Comment: Ya. my bad, [this q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), there are also other implementations that I found with the spread functionality.